# Achieving Google Earth-like 3D movement controls in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm designing a Processing model that needs to achieve similar user controls for camera movement to Google Earth, but am having issues with the perspective. The example code at the bottom provides arrow key functionality for camera x/y position and keys 'q/a' for elevation.  The initial screen looks like this:

[image]

When the camera pans right the perspective looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the plane looks tilted, but we need to look flat - more like this:

[image]

Grateful for advice what I'm missing. Do there need to be some additional rotational operations?  I've searched for Processing examples but found nothing suitable, so I'll publish any solution worked out here.  This is the model. Many thanks in advance!

```
// camera position and focus variables
float campx = 300;
float campy = 400;
float campz = 400;

// mouse control variables
float   mDifX = 0;
float   mDifY = 0;
boolean mLocked = false;
boolean kLocked = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P3D);
  fill(200);
  stroke(0);
}

void draw() {
  camera(campx, campy, campz, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);

  background(255);
  rect(0, 0, 600, 400);
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    line(0, i*40, width, i*40);
    line(i*60, 0, i*60, height);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (!mLocked) mLocked = true;
  mDifX = mouseX - campx;
  mDifY = mouseY - campy;
}

void mouseDragged() {
  if (mLocked) {
    campx = mouseX - mDifX;
    campy = mouseY - mDifY;
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  mLocked = false;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'q') {            // zoom out
    campz += 50;
  } else if (key == 'a') {     // zoom in
    campz -= 50;
  } else if (keyCode == 37) {  // camera LEFT
    campx -= 20;
  } else if (keyCode == 38) {  // camera UP
    campy -= 10;
  }  else if (keyCode == 39) { // camera RIGHT
    campx += 20;
  } else if (keyCode == 40) {  // camera DOWN
    campy += 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera setting needs to be `camera(campx, campy, campz, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 0, -1);`

Comment: The final model for anyone interested.. http://geotheory.co.uk/blog/2013/05/13/navigation-functionality-for-3d-processing-models/

Comment: @v.k. yes its a handy library but the controls setup doesn't really suit my requirement.